# python pip module installations produces WARNING Target directory /python/bin already exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip, virtualenv

In a docker container, I have python installed and virtualenv. I am installing multiple pip modules but eventually receive this error when trying to install multiple modules:

```
WARNING: Target directory /python/bin already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
```

Here's how I'm installing the pip modules:

```
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
python3 -m venv cer 
source cer/bin/activate 
pip3 install pandas -t ./python
pip3 install numpy-t ./python
pip3 install requests -t ./python # WARNING HAPPENS HERE
pip3 install xlsxwriter -t ./python # WARNING HAPPENS HERE
```

Contents of `./python/bin/` after `pandas` installation;

```
ls -lh

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 216 Dec  8 17:50 f2py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 216 Dec  8 17:50 f2py3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 216 Dec  8 17:50 f2py3.7
```

Contents of `./python/bin/` after `numpy` installation is the same as above. Contents of `./python/bin/` after `requests` installation is the same but that's when the `Target directory` **warning** appears.

If I run `pip3 install requests -t ./python --upgrade` like the WARNING suggests the **contents of** `./python/bin/` **are overwritten** with this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 244 Dec  8 17:56 normalizer
```

but in reality I would want the previous contents **not to get overwritten** & rather they get merged instead so all the pip modules installed have what they need.

How would I go about achieving this?

Or should these modules be installed in another way to avoid this problem?

Ultimately I need to upload these modules / dependencies for a lambda function I'm creating.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install the pip modules simultaneously;

```
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
python3 -m venv cer 
source cer/bin/activate 
pip3 install pandas numpy requests xlsxwriter -t ./python
```